# print matrix object in python

Tags: python, class, object, printing

I am making a board class and want a method that will allow me to print it as a matrix:

```
import numpy as np

class Board(object):

    BOARD_SIZE = 8+1
    BOARD_EDGE = range(BOARD_SIZE)

    def __init__(self):

        self.board = np.zeros( (BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE) )
        for i in BOARD_EDGE:
            self.board[i, 0] = i
            self.board[0, i] = i
```

How do I make a method to print the board similar to this:

```
board = np.zeros( (8,8) )
print board

[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [`__repr__` magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations) for your class:

```
class Board(object):

    # existing code here...

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.board)
```

This will use the representation of the `self.board` as the representation for the class instance (i.e. `print(Board())` becomes the same as `print(Board().board)`).

Note also that you should use class attributes explicitly, e.g.:

```
self.board = np.zeros((Board.BOARD_SIZE, Board.BOARD_SIZE))
```

Comment: Thanks...I'm quite new to python so I still don't get it.  Do I create a method within the board class to print it, or should I be able to just print it when I create an instance of the class?

Comment: Yes, that method should be in the class definition; I have edited my post to make that (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: Everything I try prints a result like this: `<Board.Board object at 0x10508b910>`

Comment: I did not get this behaviour. Is your indentation correct (i.e. is `__repr__` at the same level as `__init__`)? You can update your question with more information.